# Preserving Ajax page state with URL hash

Tags: ajax, hash, back-button, particles

There is a page on my site with two sets of tabs, each tab's link is ajax-driven but has a proper href in case javascript is not enabled.  I'm about to implement an ajax 'back-button' solution using a plugin such as jQuery Address.

My problem/confusion with this solution is that a page's default content is still loaded before the javascript has a chance to parse the hash and load the correct content.  If I initially hide the content, non-javascript users will never see anything.  If I don't initially hide the content, the user will see the wrong page for a moment before it gets updated (besides the extra overhead of first loading the wrong tab and then the correct tab).

What are the best / most common approaches to dealing with this?

Thanks, Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use hashes, you will always have the wrong content first. You need to use a server-side solution with the HTML5 History API to avoid this. [Read more](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling)

You can use:
https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify

And have the tabs render on the server side with something like `if ( $_GET['tab'] === '2' ) // render 2`

Comment: This is the discussion I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good question.  Have you tried using the `<noscript>` tag to include css that shows the content that's hidden initially for JS users.  Something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #area-1, #area-2 { display: none; }
</style>

<noscript>
  <style type="text/css">
    #area-1, #area-2 { display: block; }
  </style>
</noscript>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very clever, this could work.  But it still requires the overhead of loading the wrong content first (even if it's not displayed)... However, i am getting the feeling there may not be a perfect solution.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @brian Ok, now that I see the answer you accepted, I see more clearly what you were asking :)  Glad to be of a little help.

Comment: I actually opted to go with your suggestion since I won't be able to pull off the server-side solution given my time constraints.  So, thanks again.